# How to ignore 0 values in charts

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a column chart which displays player scores in real time.

The data for the chart comes from a DataTable.

I would like my chart NOT to show the players with a score of 0. Is there a way to let the chart know it should ignore zero values?

the code for the DT and chart is this:

```
this._dt = new DataTable();
this._dt.Columns.Add("Player", typeof(string));
this._dt.Columns.Add("Score", typeof(int));

foreach (Player p in getPLayerList())
{
   _dt.Rows.Add(p.Name, p.Score);
}

chartPlayers.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Players";
chartPlayers.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Score";
chartPlayers.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45;

chartPlayers.Series.Add("Frags");
chartPlayers.Series["Frags"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
chartPlayers.Series["Frags"].XValueMember = "Player";

chartPlayers.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

chartPlayers.DataSource = this._dt;
chartPlayers.DataBind();
```

Thank you

Comment: Remove them from the datasource?

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: do a foreach loop and have it check values before outputing them or not?

Comment: Seeing code or how your table is structured would help us give insight. You could remove the "0" entry with an `if-statement` inside the `for-loop`, but you have to deal with what to do with the next row if you remove the current row. Do you replace it with blank"? Shift the row up?

Comment: About what kind of *chart* are we talking? Show us your code, otherwise we won't be able to help

Comment: @TimSchmelter I can't remove them from the DT as a datagridview depends on the same DT and I want the players with zero values to show in the DGV

Comment: Why not have more than one DataGridView - then you can add a filter to your second DataGridView, and bind the chart to this DGV instead?

Comment: Can you PLEASE show code?

Comment: @173901 The chart is bound to the DT like this: chartPlayers.DataSource = this._dt; chartPlayers.DataBind();

Comment: I imagine you have some sort of collection, right?  So Collection = Collection.Where(player => player.score != 0) or something.  You'll have to post code for a better answer.

Comment: First of all what chart you're taking about ? Microsoft? Third party? and.. Winforms? Web? Or what?

Comment: @Crouzilles: but you could use two different datasources anyway. So one with all `allPlayers` for the grid and one with `allPlayers.Where(p=>p.Score>0)` for the `Chart`.

Comment: Why the vote down for the question? It is a valid programming question isn't it?

Comment: @Baldrick You cannot bind a chart to a datagridview in .net

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have create 2 DTs as you suggested and this solves the problem. Regards

Comment: @Crouzilles: You can with the chart control I use! ;) You had given no information at that point about the kind of chart that was being used... Glad you got it working anyway.

Comment: @Baldrick: as long as nothing else is stated i'm always presuming .NET controls, so the [`Charting.Chart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Fair point.

Comment: @Baldrick I believe I did mention it was a column chart, unless you mean which chart library, in this case I had not mentioned it. I am using the .NET ones :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply use  a datasource for the chart without zero-score players?

You:

> I can't remove them from the DT as a datagridview depends on the same
>   DT and I want the players with zero values to show in the DGV

But you could use different datasources anyway.

1. `allPlayers` for the `DataGridView` and
2. `allPlayers.Where(p => p.Score > 0)` for the Chart.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer for your question is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456677(v=vs.110).aspx